# Equivalent of a predicate's ANY for Swift 3 filter expression

Tags: swift3, nspredicate

When using a predicate, we can have:

```
filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY names.firstName contains[c] %@), nameToSearchFor];
```

This use of `ANY` allows us to find any object where any of the objects in the names collection has a `firstName` containing the desired text.

Is it possible to do something similar with filter expressions in Swift 3? In other words, something like:

```
allPeople.filter { $0.(ANY)names.firstName.contains(searchString) };
```

(The above ANY syntax is made up for illustration).

Perhaps could be done by nesting a `reduce` that concatenates all the firstNames, then see if my target string is contained in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allPeople.filter { $0.names.contains(where: { $0.firstName.contains(searchString) }) }
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. Are the predicate style expressions  used by filter etc documented in the Swift 3 book from Apple?

Comment: `predicate style expressions`? Huh?

Comment: I mean the "$0.names.contains(where: { $0.firstName.contains(searchString) })" bit. I had no idea that you could write 'where:' in this expression. Where is that documented?

Comment: [`contains(where:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/protocol/Sequence/#func--contains-where_) is just a method on `Sequence`, not to be confused with [`contains(_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/protocol/Sequence/#func-iterator-element_-equatable-contains_), which is only applicable to `Sequence`s of `Equatable` elements

Comment: Ah, got you, thanks. For some reason I imagined that what was between the { } was some kind of special context specific sub-language.

Comment: @occulus nope, it's just a closure